# How to add Rows to data table in C# classes

Tags: c#, .net, datatables, rows

i have a class like below.

```
class Class1
{
    private static DataTable aa = new DataTable();

    public static void AAA()
    {
        aa.Rows.Add("a", 1, "b");
        aa.Rows.Add("aasd", 123, "basf");
        aa.Rows.Add("aagh", 221, "asdb");
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");

    }
}
```

my question is how can i define columns of datatable once.and when i call AAA method i could add rows to this datatable.
First i have define columns in AAA method and when i call method for second time i have and error.

Comment: Have you looked at the MSDN docs on adding columns to a DataTable?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In the method AAA(), you need to make a check whether the columns names exists or not, if not, it means you need to add columns and If columns exists you don't need to add columns, just add data. That's it.

Comment: no.I saw that now.Problem solved. thank u.